# JS Function Always Returns False

Tags: javascript

the function below always returns false and I think I know why, but don't know how to fix it. The radio form it validates is generated using a loop, and I set the ID of each radio field to "myfilling", and I think that's where I am going wrong.

The function is:

```
if(!document.getElementById('myfilling').checked) {
    var resultloc=document.getElementById("fillingerror");
    resultloc.innerHTML =  "<span style='color:red;'>Please select a filling!<span>";
    return false;
} else {
    var resultloc=document.getElementById("fillingerror");
    resultloc.innerHTML =  "";
    return true;
}
```

If I select the first radio button in the field, there is no error.  However, if I select any of the other buttons, there's an error.  How do I fix this?

The radio field is generated with the following:

```
 function make_filling_radio($filling)
{
    $filling = array("Carne de Casa (shredded beef)", "Carnitas (shredded pork)", "Pulled BBQ Chicken", "Roasted Chili Lime Chicken", "Roasted Veggies");

    foreach ($filling as $value){
        if (!empty($filling) and (FALSE !== array_search($value, $filling)))
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"filling\" value=\"$value\" id='myfilling'> $value<br>\n";
        else
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"filling\" value=\"$value\" id='myfilling'> $value<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us how you're generating it and the relevant markup.

Comment: _and I set the ID of each radio field to "myfilling"_ - ids have to be **unique**

Comment: I realize they have to be unique, but how do I solve this? Code used to generate radio field included

Comment: *"how do I solve this"* Use unique IDs or no IDs at all.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem with pure js, you can loop through all `input` tags with `getElementsByName` (instead of using `getElementById`, since your ids are not unique):

```
var input_elements = document.getElementsByName("filling");

for (var i=0; i < input_elements.length; i++) {
  if (elements[i].checked) {
     //checked radio found
     return true;
  }
}

//...
return false;
```